# Go Protobuf Precision Decimals

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, arbitrary-precision

#### What is the correct [scalar type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar) to use in my protobuf definition file, if I want to transmit an arbitrary-precision decimal value?

I am using [shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal) instead of a float64 in my Go code to prevent math errors.  When writing my protobuf file with the intention of transmitting these values over gRPC, I could use:

- `double` which translates to a float64
- `string` which would certainly be precise in its own way but strikes me as clunky
- Something like [decimal](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/59b83356149a6df5027631421e2d6e03c8708725/src/Tools/bcl.proto#L72) from [mgravell/protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)?

Conventional wisdom has taught me to skirt floats in monetary applications, but I may be over-careful since it's a point of serialization.

Comment: my `decimal` approach isn't arbitrary-precision; it was just whatever I'd need for .NET's `System.Decimal`. For arbitrary precision with x-plat, I'd probably just go `string`. And yes: absolutely, avoid `float`/`double` for finance apps

Comment: How about a uint64 as amount of cents/minimal denomination. That's usually how money is done.

Comment: You may want to consider using sint32/64 if your number could be negative (say for debits).

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for the thoughts/feedback.  Want to make an Answer?

Comment: @thwd I have heard of that method, but it supposes that you are not in the middle of a computation and have already done your rounding.  "Minimal denomination" works great as a concept until you start dividing or multiplying by some fractional percentage or something.

Comment: Add as many powers of ten as you need to make rounding errors negligible. uint64 is huge.

Comment: We might be getting a standardized decimal type soon after all: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/7039

Answer (score 3):

If you **really** need [arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), I fear there is no correct answer right now. There is https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4406 open, but it does not seem to be very active. Without built-in support, you will really need to perform the serialization manually and then use either `string` or `bytes` to store the result. Which one to use between `string` and `bytes` likely depends on whether you need cross-platform/cross-library compatibility: if you need compatibility, use `string` and parse the decimal representation in the string using the appropriate arbitrary precision type in the reader; if you don't need it and you're going to read the data using the same cpu architecture and library you can probably just use the binary serialization provided by that library (`MarshalBinary`/`UnmarshalBinary`) and use `bytes`.

On the other hand, if you just need to send monetary values with an appropriate precision and do not need **arbitrary** precision, you can probably just use `sint64`/`uint64` and use an appropriate unit (these are commonly called [fixed-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)). To give an example, if you need to represent a monetary value in dollars with 4 decimal digits, your unit would be 1/10000th of a dollar so that e.g. the value `1` represents $0.0001, the value `19900` represents $1.99, `-500000` represents $-50, and so on. With such a unit you can represent the range $-922,337,203,685,477.5808 to $922,337,203,685,477.5807 - that should likely be sufficient for most purposes. You will still need to perform the scaling manually, but it should be fairly trivial and portable. Given the range above, I would suggest using `sint64` is preferable as it allows you also to represent negative values; `uint64` should be considered only if you need the extra positive range and don't need negative values.

Alternatively, if you don't mind importing another package, you may want to take a look at https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/money.proto or https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/decimal.proto (that incidentally implement something very similar to the two models described above), and the related utility functions at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/googleapis/go-type-adapters/adapters

As a side note, you are completely correct that you should almost never use floating point for monetary values.